# Getting translated coordinates from Android canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am passing in an object for Android to paint using it's canvas. The object to rotated to match the horizon. I am trying to find the translated points which canvas calculates given the point and angle I give it.

For example:

I use the following canvas methods to paint it. Where x,y are the screen coordinates and rotation is the rotation of the screen relative to the horizon.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(x,y);
canvas.rotate(rotation);
obj.paint(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

obj.paint() looks like this (but you probably don't need to know it):

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(-width/2, -height/2);

setFill(true);
setColor(backgroundColor);
paintRect(canvas, x, y, width, height);

setFill(false);
setColor(borderColor);
paintRect(canvas, x, y, width, height);

canvas.restore();
```

paintRect() looks like this:

```
canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width, y + height, paint);
```

What I am trying to figure out is; what are the corner points of the rectangle (green in this picture) after it has been rotated.

Here is an image of the result which is what I expect.[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the canvas.getMatrix().mapPoints() to map each rect coords individually? Although canvas.getMatrix() was deprecated in API level 16 it might be a start.

Comment: Any idea, how to do it without using the deprecated method?